# Should we support questions about installing Android on Ubuntu Touch Devices?

Tags: discussion

As listed here [in this question,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858417/meizu-mx4-from-ubuntu-to-flyme-or-cm?noredirect=1#comment1322989_858417) OP is asking for a guide on how to install Android/CM/Flyme on his MX4.

Is this off-topic?

My biggest caveat with this is that we open a can of worms regarding people bricking their phones and being unable to recover Ubuntu Touch and then complain about their ROMs.

Just looking for a quick answer here.

Comment: As far as I know, installing Windows is not on topic. I asked Bruni to clarify.

Comment: I would kindly point the OP to http://android.stackexchange.com/ as installing Android on the device is  definitely off topic here. However if the OP wanted to know how to install an Android OS under QEMU or Virtual box on Ubuntu, I would be tempted to answer that as in IMHO would then be on topic

Comment: @ElderGeek Definitely- an Android VM in Ubuntu would be on-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hell NO! Or better to say 'Hell YES! THIS IS OFF TOPIC!'

As @terdon even has pointed out in comments, even installing Windows on a pre-installed Ubuntu machine is off topic.

Answer (score 10):

Judging the tone in here, this might seem controversial but we *have* supported a range of Windows-related as part of our scope. It usually comes down to one thing...

### Interoperability.

Basically if it falls under the scope of *using* Ubuntu with another operating system, it's probably okay here.

Examples of a valid interop question might be teaching Grub to allow to boot another operating system, or perhaps picking or using an Ubuntu native filesystem, or —he said crawling right to the lonely edge of the scope— consuming an Ubuntu service (eg configuring OpenLDAP to allow Win 10 pro logins). It's not off-topic just because somebody said Windows.

Your example question here is about straight up replacing Ubuntu. I don't think that has anything to do with us... But dual booting *might* be. I honestly don't know enough about how the bootloader on a Ubuntu touch device works.

Comment: If OP had *Android* and wanted to install Ubuntu Touch via Multiboot Manager, yes, that would fall within our support. *However*, Ubuntu has no such utility.